# Indexed sections in UITableView shows but doesn't scrolls

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, sections

I have `UITableView` with countries and their phone codes

```
- (NSArray *)sortedCountryLetters {
    if (_sortedCountryLetters == nil) {
        [self countriesInfo];
    }
    return _sortedCountryLetters;
}

- (NSDictionary *)countriesInfo {
    if (_countriesInfo == nil) {
        NSMutableArray *countries = [NSMutableArray new];
        for (NSString *key in [AppDelegate phoneCodes]) {
            [countries addObject:@{
                @"key": key,
                @"name": [_locale displayNameForKey:NSLocaleCountryCode value:key],
                @"code": [AppDelegate phoneCodes][key]
            }];
        }
        NSMutableArray *firstLetters = [NSMutableArray new];
        NSMutableDictionary *result = [NSMutableDictionary new];
        for (NSDictionary *country in countries) {
            NSString *name = country[@"name"];
            NSString *firstLetter = [[name substringToIndex:1] uppercaseString];
            if ([[result allKeys] containsObject:firstLetter]) {
                NSMutableArray *letterCountries = result[firstLetter];
                [letterCountries addObject:country];
            }
            else {
                result[firstLetter] = [@[country] mutableCopy];
                [firstLetters addObject:firstLetter];
            }
        }
        [firstLetters sortUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(NSString *letter1, NSString *letter2) {
            return [letter1 compare:letter2];
        }];
        _sortedCountryLetters = [firstLetters copy];
        for (NSString *firstLetter in [result allKeys]) {
            NSMutableArray *letterCountries = result[firstLetter];
            [letterCountries sortUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(NSDictionary *obj1, NSDictionary *obj2) {
                NSString *name1 = obj1[@"name"];
                NSString *name2 = obj2[@"name"];
                return [[name1 lowercaseString] compare:[name2 lowercaseString]];
            }];
        }
        _countriesInfo = [result copy];
    }
    return _countriesInfo;
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView  {
    return [[[self countriesInfo] allKeys] count];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    NSString *firstLetter = [self sortedCountryLetters][section];
    NSArray *letterCountries = [self countriesInfo][firstLetter];
    return [letterCountries count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"countryCell"];
    NSString *firstLetter = [self sortedCountryLetters][indexPath.section];
    NSArray *letterCountries = [self countriesInfo][firstLetter];
    NSDictionary *country = letterCountries[indexPath.row];
    [[cell textLabel] setText:country[@"name"]];
    [[cell textLabel] setTextColor:[OmwThemes defaultColorForegroundMain]];
    return cell;
}

- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [self sortedCountryLetters][section];
}

- (NSArray<NSString *> *)sectionIndexTitlesForTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return [self sortedCountryLetters];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView sectionForSectionIndexTitle:(NSString *)title atIndex:(NSInteger)index {
    [tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:index] atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];
    return [[self sortedCountryLetters] indexOfObject:title];
}
```

Section indices already shows at table view right side, but tapping do nothing.

In debug I saw that `tableView:sectionForSectionIndexTitle:atIndex:` method never called.

Table view is connected to datasource and delegate. I did try both plain and group table view styles.

What did I miss?

---

**Update:**

My table view look:

[image: My table view look]

Comment: How many cells do you have on the table? Maybe, you don't have enough cells to scroll the table?

Comment: 239 rows total, it's more than enough to scroll

Comment: Can you please add the image of the table?

Comment: @FahriAzimov, I did update post

Comment: Maybe it's because of too many sections that doesn't fit to table and some sections replaced with dots?

Comment: First, are you sure your data is correctly sorting and creating the sections? Are you getting the correct values for `numberOfSectionsInTableView` and `numberOfRowsInSection`? Are your Section Headers showing up correctly in your tableview?